# smb server not showing in the Finder sidebar under Locations

Tags: unix, smb

I installed samba on linux.

- From Finder > Go > "Connect to Server …" I can connect to the server and see my folders.
- The server shows up in the Finder sidebar under Locations.
- When I unmount the server it disappears from the sidebar and doesn't come back.

What do I need to do so the server always shows up in the sidebar when it's running?

I've tried various things I've found on the web. No joy.

- macOS 10.14.3
- samba 2:4.5.16+dfsg-1
- Linux pi 4.14.98-v7+ #1200 SMP Tue Feb 12 20:27:48 GMT 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you manage to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that this is the result of something in your network configuration: e.g. DNS, or maybe DHCP. I'll assume you've not "tweaked" your macos network configuration.

When I've had issues similar to yours, I've been able to clear it up by installing [`avahi`](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/reports/6826/1) on the reluctant Linux host.  If your Linux host’s name is *“jethro”*, it will become *jethro.local* under the "zero configuration networking" scheme used by avahi and Apple's Bonjour.

You can easily check to see if `avahi` is installed on your Linux host; one way is type `man avahi` at the command line. If the `man page` is there, then `avahi` is almost certainly installed. If it's installed, you can check to be sure it's running:

```
$ ps -ax | grep avahi 
... You should see something like this as the output:
  346 ?        Ss     0:20 avahi-daemon: running [raspberrypi3b.local]
  383 ?        S      0:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
```

Where `raspberrypi3b.local` is the Linux host from which I ran this command.

If it's not installed, there's almost certainly an `avahi` package for your distro. Install it, and let us know if that resolves your issue.

If `avahi` is installed & running, and you see a similar output to mine, then my guess/answer probably won't help you. You may want to try one of the other SE sites to get help troubleshooting.

Also, there's a good overview of zero config networking, and Bonjour in particular, in this [Server Fault SE Q&A](https://serverfault.com/questions/118652/how-to-use-bonjour)

Comment: I have avahi running on all my linux machines. But they only show up inside the "Network" folder, not directly under "Locations".